# INNER JOIN en una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero hacer que dos datos de mi misma tabla aparezcan utilizando el INNER JOIN, necesito listar el nombre y apellido de los clientes que tienen el jefe de familia Martha Carrizalez, al momento que los uno me aparece asi:

```
select a.id as nombre,
b.jefefamilia as jefefamilia 
from cliente as a join cliente as b 
on a.nombre = b.jefefamilia ;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual necesito que me aparezca el nombre de los cliente que tienen como jefe de familia martha carrizales, este es el codigo de la tabla:

```
create table cliente (
id bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
nombre varchar (45), 
telefono bigint ,
direccion varchar (100),
ciudad varchar (20),
destino varchar (20),
jefefamilia varchar (20)
);
```

Comment: los códigos de la imagen van como texto por favor

Comment: perdona @BetaM, pense que lo habia pegado, ahora ya lo escribo

Comment: Aquí `jefefamilia varchar (20)` guardas el nombre o una referencia a otra tabla?

Comment: Lo guardo como nombre

Comment: Entonces el inner join lo veo de mas, por que no simplemente haces un `SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE jefefamilia = 'alguien'`  ???

Comment: Si, ya lo he hecho pero ahora mismo estoy cursando el curso de mysql por lo tanto necesito realizar las relaciones recursiva que puede tener una misma tabla, usando INNER JOIN. Por eso el problema.

Comment: Lo mismo he discutido por que arroja el mismo resultado, sin la necesidad de dar tantas vueltas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la siugiente manera:

- Elijo todas las columnas deseadas
- Hago un `INNER JOIN` con la misma tabla, dándole un alias a la misma en este paso
- En la parte de `ON` se me ocurre que igualemos llaves primarias (*asumiendo que existe esta columna*), pues este registro es el que nos identifica de manera única a cada uno de los registros y con esto encontraremos registros en *ambas tablas* que cumplan la igualdad
- Cuando hago el `WHERE` indico de cual de las 2 tablas (la que posee el nombre o la que posee el alias) obtendremos la columna para evaluar una condición

Consulta:

```
SELECT  a.id AS nombre,
        b.jefefamilia AS jefefamilia 
FROM    cliente AS a 
INNER JOIN cliente AS b 
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.jefefamilia = 'algo';
```

Comment: Ahora la pruebo y te comento como me funciona, gracias por tomarte la molestia.

Comment: Listo, me funciono de maravilla, muchas gracias por la explicacion ahora ya tambien he podido resolver algunos problemas mas.